# Sample Identity Provider SAML 2.0

Tags: java, single-sign-on, saml, saml-2.0, service-provider

I have developed my sample Service Provider which works perfectly with **http://www.ssocircle.com/en/**. Is there any other **online Identity Provider** available for testing my Service Provider or any link to get sample code for **Service Provider** to understand **SAML 2.0**.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

You can use https://www.testshib.org/ both for a test Identity Provider. Also, take a look at [opensaml](https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home) library for code and examples.